# Url redirection in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, joomla1.5

i am having a url like
http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=3&Itemid=55

and i want to redirect this to 
http://localhost/joomla/Joomla1.5/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=3&Itemid=55

Not only this redirection but whenever i have anything next to Joomla_1.5.7/ i am trying to attach that to Joomla1.5 ..
How to do this in PHP ....
How to identify that the url contains something after Joomla_1.5.7 to get it??

EDIT:
      ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
       Options +FollowSymLinks

```
#
  #  mod_rewrite in use

  RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
   ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
   ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
   #
   # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
  # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
```

# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
   #
    ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

```
#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


  ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

#
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|.php|.html|.htm|.feed|.pdf|.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
      RewriteRule (.*) index.php
     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
    #
      ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/joomla/Joomla_1\.5\.7/.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/joomla/Joomla1.5/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is the content in my htaccess file but still it showed any changes in my site.

Comment: This is the same as the question you asked three hours earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644217/php-script-for-redirecting-to-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with an htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/(.*?)$ joomla/Joomla1.5/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But if you absolutely want to achieve it with PHP, put this in the old index.php:

```
header("Status: 301");
header("Location: http://localhost/joomla/Joomla1.5/index.php".(!empty($_GET) ? '?'.http_build_query($_GET) : ''));
exit;
```

Comment: `implode('&', $_GET)` will yield value1&value2&value3, and break (e.g. value1&Array&Array&value4 with errors generated) on arrays. Take a look at http://php.net/http_build_query instead.

Comment: That'll still break on arrays, since it has no recursion. Not a fan of `http_build_query()`?

Comment: +1 for the mod_rewrite solution, I would add R=permanent to the rule (to make it a 301 redirect), thus: RewriteRule ^joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/(.*?)$ joomla/Joomla1.5/$1 [R=permanent,L,QSA]

Comment: Added the R=permanent to the answer. Also, pinkgothic, I didn't even know such a function existed. Let me look at it for a moment, I'll update the answer then... EDIT: updated

Comment: I tried the R=permanent on my own host, but that messed up something. I removed it from the answer for now.
I think it works if you redirect to a completely new URL, though.

Comment: @Dragory: Yay for polished answers! :D Not that it's up to me, but I would accept this one. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you have [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html), in your .htaccess you can put something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/joomla/Joomla_1\.5\.7/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/joomla/Joomla1.5/$1 [L]
```

Basically, it matches any incoming URL that starts with /joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/ and redirects it to /joomla/Joomla1.5/, with all the extra parameters intact, but the URL won't change in the user's address bar.

If you want the URL to change, you can change the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/joomla/Joomla1.5/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!